# Error when linking with POCO library compiled with i686-w64-mingw32

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, poco

I am using i686-w64-mingw32 downloaded from sf to compile POCO libraries. Libraries are compiled and libPoco*.a files are created (with some warnings).
Now when I want to use those files (e.g. in a small sample project which converts string to integer), linker throws error saying: **./Debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN4Poco12NumberParser5parseERKSs'**

The strange thing is that if I do compilation for both sides (lib and test app) using TDM-MinGW-4.7.1 everything is fine!

I tried setting "-march=i386;-m32" on both compilations but no luck. Here is log of linker when I try to build my test app:

```
g++ -o ./Debug/testpoco @"testpoco.txt" -L. -Lc:/poco/lib/  -lPocoFoundationmtd  -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
...
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
...
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' './Debug/testpoco.exe' '-L.' '-Lc:/poco/lib/' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
...
./Debug/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco12NumberParser5parseERKSs'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/testpoco] Error 1
testpoco.mk:77: recipe for target 'Debug/testpoco' failed
```

Comment: Well, Well, Well! I fixed it. Linker was looking for '_impl_xxxx' symbol while the symbol in static lib was 'xxxx'. I had to define 'POCO_STATIC' in my client application. That was all!

Answer (score 1):

Usually errors like this are threw only when you have not linked your library properly. Are you sure thatlibPocoFoundationmtd.a  contains this function? And if you do, what warnings are shown when you compiled those libraries. Check these too

Make sure you defined all needed preprocessor symbols! (-D) eg: POCO_STATIC

Comment: I used ar and objDump to view contents of library and object file of the class for which linker is complaining. It seems that the symbol in object file is named '__ZN4Poco12NumberParser5parseERKSs' while linker gives undef-ref error for '_imp___ZN4Poco12NumberParser5parseERKSs'.

Comment: 11 Warning are related to visibility attribute: C:/poco/Foundation/src/inffast.c:324:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]

Comment: Maybe you need to define some preprocessors? (-D)